# Trying to bound the generalized hypergeometric function ${}_2F_3(x+1,x+1;1,1,1;\alpha)$ as $x\to \infty$?

Tags: special-functions, asymptotics, hypergeometric-functions

(See also edit below)...

I am trying to get a nice, explicit, bound on the hypergeometric function
$$
{}_2F_3(a_1,a_2;b_1,b_2,b_3;\alpha),
$$
in the case of a large parameter. In particular I am interested in the case where
$$
{}_2F_3(x+1,x+1;1,1,1;\alpha), \quad \quad x \to \infty.
$$

I found [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43601366?seq=1) paper that shows how we can decompose hypergeometric functions into sums of hypergeometric functions of lower orders, when they have integer parameters differences.

Using the method in the paper I decomposed the above function as
\begin{align*}
{}_2F_3(x+1,x+1;1,1,1;\alpha) & = \sum_{j=0}^x  {x\choose j} {}_1F_2(x+1+j;1+j,1+j;\alpha) \frac{(x+j)!}{x!(j!)!} \alpha^j \\
\end{align*}

I then bound the binomial coefficient with ${x\choose j}\le (ex)^j(1/j)^j$, and applied Sterling's approximation $(1/j)^j \le 1/(j!e^j)$ to get:
\begin{align*}
{}_2F_3(x+1,x+1;1,1,1;\alpha) & \le \sum_{j=0}^x  x^j {}_1F_2(x+1+j;1+j,1+j;\alpha) \frac{(x+j)!}{x!(j!)^4} \alpha^j \\
\end{align*}

However, while the hypergeometric function has now been reduced, I don't seem to be any closer to being able to get a nice explicit expression.

Somewhat surprisingly, upon running some numerics, simply neglecting the ${}_2F_1$ seems to still give an excellent approximation (yellow line in image):

\begin{align*}
{}_2F_3(x+1,x+1;1,1,1;\alpha) & \lessapprox \sum_{j=0}^x  x^j \frac{(x+j)!}{x!(j!)^4} \alpha^j \\
\end{align*}
[image]

Here, $\alpha=1/4$ was used.

But even with that simplification, I don't seem to be much better off when it comes to letting $x\to \infty$ and finding an explicit bound; I am looking for bound that doesn't feature a series/integral/special function.

The function looks pretty straightforward on the plot so I would hope it is possible to get a nice bound for it. Apart from my attempt above, I have looked through a lot of literature for useful identities/techniques but haven't been able to find anything.

So is it possible to get a nice explicit bound on this function?

**EDIT:**
Ok, it seems there is another simplification (numerically at least for the moment); it seems we can 'transfer' the $x$ and reduce (blue line in image)
$$
{}_2F_3(x+1,x+1;1,1,1;\alpha)
$$
to (green line in image):
$$
{}_0F_3(;1,1,1;x^2\alpha) 
$$

[image]

So this suggests that it may be possible to get a nice bound on ${}_2F_3(x+1,x+1;1,1,1;\alpha)$ if we can find an asymptotic representation of ${}_0F_3(;1,1,1;x^2\alpha)$ for large x?

Note that ${}_0F_3(;1,1,1;x^2\alpha) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (1/j!)^4 (x^2\alpha)^j$.

Comment: You can find the asymptotics for large $x$ by using the method of steepest descent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done much of the work for yourself. Here is the last missing step:

Writing the $_2 F_3$ as integral (see, e.g., http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.5.E1):
$$
_2 F_3(x+1,x+1;1,1,1;\alpha)=\Gamma(x+1)^{-2}\ \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\cal{L}} d s \frac{\Gamma(x+1+s)^2}{\Gamma(s+1)^3} \ \Gamma(-s) \ (-\alpha)^s,
$$
where the path $\cal{L}$ is described in the source given above. Then we insert the approximation for large $x$ (see, e.g., http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E12)
$$
\left(\frac{\Gamma(x+1+s)}{\Gamma(x+1)}\right)^2 \sim x^{2 s} .
$$
Therefore for large $x$
$$
_2 F_3(x+1,x+1;1,1,1;\alpha)\sim \int_{\cal{L}} d s \ \Gamma(s+1)^{-3} \ \Gamma(-s) \ (-\alpha x^2 )^s = \ _0 F_3(;1,1,1;x^2 \ \alpha),
$$
which gives you the desired asymptotic similarity.

Comment: Thanks, I also found an alternative explanation in the meantime. To get the relationship, we can apply the [formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.8) in 16.8(iii) on this page twice.

Answer (score 1):

I found large argument asymptotics in for ${}_0F_3$ in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521140633) book, specifically Formula 16.11.9.

Using these, I obtained
\begin{align}
{}_2F_3(x+1,x+1;1,1,1;\alpha) \approx {}_0F_3(;1,1,1;x^2\alpha) \sim Ce^{4(x^2 \alpha)^{1/4}}, \quad x\to \infty,
\end{align}
where $C > 0$. Numerics confirm it.

Now I just need to find out why ${}_2F_3(x+1,x+1;1,1,1;\alpha) \approx {}_0F_3(;1,1,1;x^2\alpha)$...